# Execute a command with superuser permission in JNI method in Android

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface

In Java, I can have something like this:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
DataOutputStream pOut = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());
pOut.writeBytes("find / -perm -2000 -o -perm -4000\n");
pOut.writeBytes("ps\n");
pOut.writeBytes("ls\n");
pOut.writeBytes("exit\n");
pOut.flush();
p.waitFor();
```

I know that to execute the find command in JNI method, we can use **system** or **popen** function. But I don't know how to execute it with su privilege?

PS: Since the system function forks a new child process. I want to have a single child process spawning up to execute multiple commands like in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Femi answer is close, I have tested, the following works for me:

```
system("su -c \"find / -perm -2000 -o -perm -4000; ps; ls\"");
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't see what's the point for you to use system() to execute, system() doesn't return you stream to read the output.

I think you should try popen() instead

Comment: Thanks your and Vi Vi's answer. You 2 made my days :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have `su` installed on your Android device and it is in the path, you could try it like this:

```
system("su -c \"find / -perm -2000 -o -perm -4000\" root");
```

`su` accepts arguments: the `-c` argument specifies a command to run.

EDIT: you might be out of luck there. I'm not sure if you can pass multiple commands to the `su` command. You might get away with passing it a shell and then passing that shell commands, but no guarantees there.

```
system("su -c \"sh -c 'find / -perm -2000 -o -perm -4000; rm /tmp/1'\" root");
```

Comment: Please check my edit, since the system function forks a new child process. I want to have a single child process spawning up to execute multiple commands like in Java.